# Address of bluetooth adapter on Android8

Tags: java, android

Неожиданно обнаружил неработающий код при тестировании под Андроид8.

```
        sBtaName = bluetoothAdapter.getName();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            sAddress = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address");
        else
            sAddress = bluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```

Переменная `sAddress`  всегда возвращает `null`.

`android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` получены.

В 7 и 6 версиях всё работает нормально. Поиском на developer.android.com ничего не обнаружил. Что делать- не знаю.
Если кто в курсе, помогите плиз.